# Use for-loop in LuaTeX to include many subchapters

Tags: luatex, babel, loops

I have many files called 1.tex, ..., 85.tex which I want to include into my document like this:

```
\include{chapters/text/1}
[...]
\include{chapters/text/85}
```

As I use LuaLaTeX, I thought I could use something like this to keep my main document clean:

```
\directlua{
  for i=1,85,1 do
    tex.sprint("\\include{chapters/text/", i, "} ")
  end
}
```

However, this gives me an error:

```
> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
> 
> \reserved@a ^^@-\def \reserved@a 
>                                *{\@vspacer }\reserved@a  l.102     tex.sprint("\\
>                       include{chapters/text/", i, "}")
```

I already found [this introduction](http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Writing_Lua_in_TeX) into programming with Lua in TeX and got the feeling that this error has something to do with the curly braces -- but I don't see how I should change the code to make it work...

---

EDIT: A minimal example, adapted from David Carlisle's answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{text/1.tex}
Das ist ein Test.
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{text/2.tex}
Noch ein Test.
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\directlua{
  for i=1,2,1 do
    tex.sprint("\string\\include{text/", i, "} ")
  end
}
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
> Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }. <inserted text> 
> \par  l.13     tex.sprint("\string\\include{text/", i, "}
>                                                   ")
```

The error goes away upon removing `babel`. To me the problem seems to be that the `ngerman` option makes `"` an active character...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are expanding `\\` to its newline meaning *before* calling lua.

Use

```
 tex.sprint("\string\\include{
```

same issue in your added babel example, you are expanding `"` too early as a babel shorthand.

You can disable all Tex expansion of the argument via:

```
\directlua{\detokenize{
  for i=1,2,1 do
    tex.sprint("\\include{text/", i, "} ")
  end
}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I run into problems when using babel. I've added a non-working example.

Comment: @FredFisch same issue with quotes (which are active in babel) I updated answer